# RegEx giving non characters with \w

Tags: regex, python-3.x

```
c = re.split(r'\w+', message)
print(c)
```

message contains '!nano speak', but the regex is giving me this in return:

```
>>> ['!', ' ', '\r\n']
```

I'm very new to regex, but this seems like something I should get, and I can't seem to find this problem in search. It seems like it's doing exactly the opposite, and I'm sure it's a lower-case w.

Comment: What exactly is your desired output?

Comment: Sorry, I am expecting ['nano', 'speak']. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split) is using the regex as a delimiter to split the string. You set the delimiter to be any number of alphanumeric characters. This means that it will return everything *between* words.

In order to get the tokens defined by the regex you can use [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall):

```
>>> re.findall(r'\w+', '!nano speak')
['nano', 'speak']
```

Comment: That was it. Thank you very much. I understand the difference now. What is an appropriate use for re.split?

I see now that I delimited my input by all letters, removing precisely what I wanted xD

Comment: Click on the link on re.split in the answer to see some use case.

Answer (score 0):

`\w` matches word character (alphanumeric and underscore), so in the string "!nano speak", it matches everything except "!" and the space, then splitting according to "nano" and "space". So you get "!", " " and "\r\n".

To remove all non characters, you should

```
re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]+", "", "!nano speak")
```